# Iterate through dictionary, separate into arrays and output

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm fairly new to Python, can anyone help with the solution?

I have a 3-4 layer directories with files in them. All files have data in them in the following format:

```
data1:data2

data3:data4

data5:data6
```

...

I want to iterate through files and read all lines, add them to an array and output only data after the comma.

This is what I attempted:

```
import os

output_file = input("Enter output file: ")
folder_location = input("Enter directory: ")
while os.path.isdir(folder_location) is False:
    print("Directory not found, enter again: ")
    folder_location = input("Enter directory: ")

for subdir, dirs, files in os.os.walk(folder_location):
    for file in files:
        file = open()
        for line in file:
            fields = line.split(":")
            email = fields[0]
            password = fields[1]
```

Output should look like this in a new file:

```
data2

data4

data6
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to slightly edit your question title and tag so it says `directory`. `dictionary` is a related but different concept that is quite important in Python, but may be misleading if used to refer to a file system structure. A clear title and tags helps your question attract more people who are able to answer it.

Comment: Actually, now I wonder whether it may be the data inside your files that you refer to as "dictionary". As this is likely only relevant to the purpose of your program, but irrelevant to your question and [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) already has a predefined meaning in Python, this may still be a bit misleading.

Comment: `str.split(":")[1]`?

Comment: Thanks for your input, yes dictionary refers to data inside files. And thanks for the `str.split(":") [1]`. How do I output it to file after this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
with open('result_file.txt', 'w') as result_file:

    for directory, _, filenames in os.walk(folder_location):

        for filename in filenames:
            full_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

            with open(full_path, 'r') as source_file:
                for line in source_file:
                    stripped = line.rstrip()
                    email, password = stripped.split(':', maxsplit=1)

                    print(password, file=result_file)
```

`maxsplit=1` ensures that your string is split into 2 components at most. This is important in the case the password also contains a colon. Without `maxsplit=1` that would give you 3 components - i.e. the last two would be split in the middle of the password.

If you're using Python 2.7, the `print()` function with `file=` support won't be available by default, but you can make it available by putting this at the top of your program:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

If you're stuck with an even older Python version or don't want to use `print()`, you can do this instead:

```
result_file.write(password + "\n")
```